# Regex match certain string and ignore if it starts with some pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a following regular expression that I use in C# code that tries to match `save some` followed by some word and `delete some` followed by some word in a file.

`\bsave\ssome\b\s[^\s]+|\bdelete\ssome\b\s[^\s]+`

This works as expected. Now, I wanted to exclude those from the match that has a pattern like `- save some` and `- delete some`.

I tried using the following but it didn't work. In the expression below I just used the expression to ignore `- save some` Appreciate any help.
`(?!-\s\bsave\ssome\b\s[^\s])(\bsave\ssome\b\s[^\s]+|\bdelete\ssome\b\s[^\s]+)`

The demo is [here](http://regexr.com/3ciui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative look-behind and group the pattern:

```
(?<!-\p{Zs}*)(?:\bsave\ssome\b\s[^\s]+|\bdelete\ssome\b\s[^\s]+)
^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^                                                ^
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!-%5Cp%7BZs%7D*)(%3F%3A%5Cbsave%5Cssome%5Cb%5Cs%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%2B%7C%5Cbdelete%5Cssome%5Cb%5Cs%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%2B)&i=%20-%20save%20some%20and%20-%20delete%20some.%0D%0A%20save%20some%20and%20delete%20some%20here.)

The `(?<!-\p{Zs}*)` lookbehind fails a match if the `save/delete` some is preceded with `-` followed by zero or more spaces (use `+` if there must be at least one). I used `\p{Zs}` to only match *horizontal* whitespace. If you want to match newlines, use `\s`.

A contracted regex version:

```
(?<!-\s*)\b(save|delete)\ssome\b\s\S+
```

Use the `Explicit Capture` flag with [it](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!-%5Cs*)%5Cb(save%7Cdelete)%5Cssome%5Cb%5Cs%5CS%2B&i=%20-%20save%20some%20and%20-%20delete%20some.%0D%0A%20save%20some%20and%20delete%20some%20here.&o=n). Since `\ssome\b\s\S+` is common for both alternatives, you can move the end of the group to just include `save` and `delete`.

C#:

```
var rx = @"(?<!-\s*)\b(save|delete)\ssome\b\s\S+";
```